# React Native Geolocation.watchPosition not working in Android emulator

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, geolocation

It's crucial for me to have location updates and emulation of a route in the android emulator. But all I get is a single update on the map and nothing more.

Can't seem to find any good examples of "watchPosition" using functional components.

What am I missing? Here's some of the code I'm using:

```js
...

import Geolocation from "@react-native-community/geolocation";

...

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      handlePosition,
      handlePositionError,
      geoConfig
    );

    return () => Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);

  }, []);

  const geoConfig = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 20000,
    maximumAge: 1000,
  };

  const handlePosition = info => {
    console.log("getting position");
    setMyLocation({
      latitude: info.coords.latitude,
      longitude: info.coords.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
      longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta,
    });
    if (isMine) {
      const position = {
        latitude: info.coords.latitude,
        longitude: info.coords.longitude,
      };
      updateRideDriverPosition(ride.rideId, position, () =>
        console.log("Yay! position updated")
      );
    } else {
      (async () =>
        await getRideById(ride.rideId).then(item => {
          setCarLocation({
            latitude: item.position.latitude,
            longitude: item.position.longitude,
          });
        }))();
    }
  };

  const handlePositionError = error => console.log(new Date(), error);

...
```

I tried to just use "getPosition" inside an interval and that worked fine, also the google maps app works fine and updates the location the whole route I configured.

How can I get continuous responses with new locations?

Answer (score 0):

Add these options to geoConfig and try.

```
interval: 100,
distanceFilter: 1,
```